# Can one programmatically refresh a Tableau report without Tableau Server?

Tags: autoit, tableau-api

I have Tableau Desktop 9.2, Professional Edition. I would like to be able to have a scheduled job which would open a workbook, refresh a dashboard, and generate a PDF. Can anyone suggest a way?

UPD. I came across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsJRD4iJmwI) approach, suggested by Dafang Wu.

My current AutoIt script is

```
Local $tableaufile = "C:\test.twb"

WinActivate($tableaufile);
WinWaitActive($tableaufile);

Send("!f",0);
Send("D");

WinWaitActive("Print to PDF");
Send("{ENTER}"); Send enter key
WinWaitActive("Save PDF");
Send("test unique name");
Send("{ENTER}");
```

Unfortunately, this does not work: when I open the script in SciTE Script Editor and hit F5, the process does not exit - I have to Ctrl-Break - and there is no PDF file.

UPD2. Corrected the first WinWait call, and switched to MouseClick's - still no joy.

```
Local $tableaufile = "C:\Users\Dimitri Shvorob\Documents\My Tableau Repository\Workbooks\test.twb"
WinActivate($tableaufile);
WinWait("Tableau - test", 10);
Send("!f",0);
Send("D");
MouseClick("Left", 829, 523);
MouseClick("Left", 1248, 690);
WinKill("Tableau - test");
```

Answer (score 0):

With Dafang's help, I got the script to work. A problem with my previous attempts is that these were meant to be run with the workbook already open. (Duh!)

```
$tableau = "C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 9.2\bin\tableau.exe"

Run($tableau);
WinWait("Tableau - Book1");
Send("!f");
Send("^o");

WinWait("Open");
Send("Graham");
Send("{ENTER}");

WinWait("Tableau - Graham");

Send("!f"); 
Send("D");

WinWait("Print to PDF");
Send("{ENTER}");

WinWait("Save PDF");
Send("Graham Test");
Send("{ENTER}");

WinKill("Tableau - Graham");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same thing using the TabCmd like this

```
tabcmd login -s http://tableauserver -u *user* -p *password*
tabcmd export "Project/Dashboardname?:refresh=yes" --width 1920 --height 1080 --png -f "\\server\path\dashboardname.png"
```